# Create new variable (with values rep(c(1,2) depending on repeating values in other variable

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R and currently working on the following problem:

I have a data frame set more or less structured as follows:

```
    Filename                     
    F_W07FP_W10HS_TalkTurns_I1.docx        0
    F_W07FP_W10HS_TalkTurns_I1.docx        1
    F_W07FP_W10HS_TalkTurns_I1.docx        2
    F_S02BE_G04KH_TalkTurnsI1.docx         1
    F_S02BE_G04KH_TalkTurnsI1.docx         1
    F_S02BE_G04KH_TalkTurnsI1.docx         1
    F_S02BE_G04KH_TalkTurnsI1.docx         2
    F_S02BE_G04KH_TalkTurnsI1.docx         3
    F_L05RJ_L11SM_Talk TurnsI1.docx        5 
    F_L05RJ_L11SM_Talk TurnsI1.docx        2
    F_L05RJ_L11SM_Talk TurnsI1.docx        1
```

Now I want to add a new column with repeating values c(1,2) which works fine if I only do this:

```
    data_rLSM[,length(data_rLSM[1,])+1] <-rep(c(1,2))
```

But in my final data set I need the values 1,2 to start again depending on the values in the first line. So I need R to restart counting from one when the values in the first column change. Filename always is my first column whereas speaker is always added behind the last column. In the end it should look like this:

```
    Filename                               x   Speaker
    F_W07FP_W10HS_TalkTurns_I1.docx        0   1 
    F_W07FP_W10HS_TalkTurns_I1.docx        1   2 
    F_W07FP_W10HS_TalkTurns_I1.docx        2   1 
    F_S02BE_G04KH_TalkTurnsI1.docx         1   1
    F_S02BE_G04KH_TalkTurnsI1.docx         1   2
    F_S02BE_G04KH_TalkTurnsI1.docx         1   1
    F_S02BE_G04KH_TalkTurnsI1.docx         2   2 
    F_S02BE_G04KH_TalkTurnsI1.docx         3   1
    F_L05RJ_L11SM_Talk TurnsI1.docx        5   1
    F_L05RJ_L11SM_Talk TurnsI1.docx        2   2 
    F_L05RJ_L11SM_Talk TurnsI1.docx        1   1
```

I've been trying this:

```
for(i in 1:name)

{
data_rLSM[length(data_rLSM[1,])+1] <-rep_len(c(1,2), length.out = length(unique(data_rLSM[,i]))
 }
```

But to be honest, I have absolutely no idea what I am doing. I would really appreciate some good ideas or ways to tackle my problem :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(filename = c(rep('a', 3), rep('b', 4), rep('c', 2)))
```

And then:

```
require(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(., filename) %>%
  mutate(., Speaker = rep(c(1, 2), length.out = n()))
```

And we are done!